# Is linking to a related question an abuse of the comment box?

Tags: discussion

I was told that adding a comment to a question with a link to a related question that contains good answers was "an abuse of the comment box". That user flagged the comment for removal, and apparently a mod agreed with this claim, because the comment was then removed. When I flagged this user with a request my comment to be reinstated, a diamond mod came along and claimed that this user was technically correct, because "comments are meant to be temporary".

Here is the [stackexchange meta guide to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> When should I comment?
>
> Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. ***a link
> to a related question***

(emphasis mine).

I note that adding a link to related questions is a use of the comment box that can be found built in to the Stackexchange software itself, for example it is done automatically upon closing questions as duplicate.

I've been on stackexchange for over a decade, but am not very active on biology.stackexchange. I'd like to get some more opinions on this behavior that looks totally divorced from good manners, as well as written rules, and long established SE practice. But this view was apparently sanctioned by two different mods, so maybe things are different over here and the community can clarify.

Comment: As meta suggests, linking to related posts is ok and not an "abuse." In fact, sometimes it's quite helpful for directing OP's/visitor's thinking/learning or even helping to point out duplicated questions. That being said.... from [Bryan's answer below](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4367/16866), it sounds like your situation is a bit unique. As the OP, it is better to include links in your question post directly vs. as a potentially transient comment. I disagree with the "abuse" rationale you were given, but I do agree with our other mod moving your comment into your post's body. Thx

Answer (score 5):

You're the post owner. You don't need to provide other information for OP, because OP is you.

Comments are transient; if you want to maintain some piece of information that you think is relevant to your post, use the edit function to add it to your post. You can edit your post as many times as you want as long as the edits are  constructive. Since you've made clear that you want to preserve this information, it shouldn't be transient!

I've edited the relevant content from your comment into the question that raised this issue to demonstrate.

There's no penalty here, you're not being punished for this, it's just part of how to best organize information within questions and answers which are the primary purpose/content of Stack Exchange. "Abuse" is overstating it, but it's just better practice in this case to add to the post itself and to recognize that comments can be removed any time.

Comment: Comments are for transient or relevant but minor information. I considered the link to be in the latter category, and I believe it is standard practice to link in this fashion.

Comment: I agree that editing it into the post is fine, perhaps even preferable in some situations. So I am grateful to you for recovering the deleted comment and adding it to the post. Thank you. It is an acceptable outcome.